# É possível fazer perguntas ou mandar mensagens para usuários específicos?

Tags: suporte

Sou novato aqui no site e ainda estou tentando aprender mais sobre as funções, nessa tentativa de aprendizado eis que me surgiu uma dúvida, procurei então descobrir se tal ação era possível e não achei nada sobre isso. Pelo fato de eu não ter encontrado nada estou recorrendo a usuários mais avançados. A minha duvida já foi exposta no próprio enunciado, então acho desnecessário repita-la.

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1361/o-sopt-se-encaixa-na-categoria-de-rede-social

Comment: Ivan, se você continuar com dúvidas e quiser uma opinião pessoal de alguém, pode usar o chat. Se não me engano é necessário ter 20 pontos para isso, mas acho que não seria um problema para você. O bate-papo pode ser acessado pelo menu Stack Exchange ali em cima.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O formato do site não permite que você poste perguntas para usuários específicos ou até mesmo enviar mensagens privadas.

Os sites da Stack Exchange foram criados para que a internet possa se beneficiar da solução das suas dúvidas, por isso todas as questões são públicas e disponíveis para toda a comunidade responder e participar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: *Não é um fórum; não é uma rede social; é um site de Perguntas & Respostas*

Comment: Apesar de ser um recurso desejável em certas ocasiões, é até bom que não tenha tal recurso. Mesmo que não seja lá muito fácil para um recém-chegado de encontrar os usuários que mais colaboram com a comundiade, se houvesse o recurso de MP, sempre haveria mais um usuário que se daria ao trabalho de procurar membro bem reputado e ficar aporrinhando ele com questões que, de repente não são nem da área dele, coisa que é muito como noutro fórum que participo onde os mais reputados ficam bem destacados.